# Method returning the wrong value

Tags: c, methods, return-value

I'm learning programming in C and C#. This C code is not computing as expected. The method returns the value: -504476904 to the console? What can be the problem here?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int minimum(values)
int values[10];
{
  int minimum_value, i;

  minimum_value = values[0];

  for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
  {
      if(values[i] < minimum_value)
      {
          minimum_value = values[i];
      }
  }

  return (minimum_value);
}

int main()
{
   int sumthing[10];
   int i;
   for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
   {
       sumthing[i] = (i * 34);
   }

   printf("Minimum value of for loop is: %d\n", minimum(sumthing));

   return 0;
}
```

I changed my code to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int minimum(values)
int values[10];
{
    int minimum_value, i;

    minimum_value = values[0];

    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
       if(values[i] < minimum_value)
       {
           minimum_value = values[i];
       }
    }

    return (minimum_value);
```

}

```
int main()
{
   int sumthing[10];
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       sumthing[i] = ((i + 1 )* 34);
   }

   printf("Minimum value of for loop is: %d\n", minimum(sumthing));

   return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sumthing[0]` is not initialized in your code, since you start looping at index 1 ; that is a first step to correct your program, in the `main`function :

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   sumthing[i] = (i * 34);
}
```

BTW, you're using K&R style. This is considered obsolete.

A more modern implementation of your code, with the above correction ; it seems to be working :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int minimum(int values[])
{
  int minimum_value, i;

  minimum_value = values[0];

  for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
  {
      if(values[i] < minimum_value)
      {
          minimum_value = values[i];
      }
  }

  return (minimum_value);
}

int main()
{
   int sumthing[10];
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       sumthing[i] = (i * 34);
   }

   printf("Minimum value of for loop is: %d\n", minimum(sumthing));

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'm programming from an old book I have, I started by having this value i = 0, but I wanted to see the second lowest value, because the first was zero. When I run the program like it is now, it gives the wrong result.

Comment: @somethingSomething : beware I'm talking about the loop in the `main`function ; the one in the `minimum` function is correct, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @fabien Thanks for the comments about the old style, but I'm using this old book, and thought it would be of value to learn about the old style also.

Answer (score -1):

This syntax is very, very archaic:

```
/* Don't do this */
int minimum(values)
int values[10];
{
  ...

/* Do this instead */
int minimum(int values[10])
{
  ...
```

Other than that, I looks fine.

I copied/pasted your code, changed "minimum()" to `int minimum(int values[10])`, ran it ... and got the correct result "34":

> Minimum value of for loop is: 34

Comment: I'm programming from a old book. Thanks

Comment: ALSO: Indexes are 0..9, not 1..10.  That's true of any version of C :)

Comment: :( then it is something with my setup.

Comment: It works by sheer luck. Try to compile it with other optimization options, like `-O3`, you might get other results. Or not. But `sumthing[0]` cannot be initialized in OP's code, but its value is read from.

Comment: I cannot see anything in this answer to justify down votes.  More SO shenanigans?